# How to resize image in ASP.NET (with C#) application in optimizable way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code written in C#:

```
            int maxSideSize = 125;
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream( File.ReadAllBytes( Path.GetFullPath( "test1.png" ) ) );
            Image img = Image.FromStream( memory );

            //Determine image format 
            ImageFormat fmtImageFormat = img.RawFormat;

            //get image original width and height 
            int intOldWidth = img.Width;
            int intOldHeight = img.Height;

            //determine if landscape or portrait 
            int intMaxSide;
            if ( intOldWidth >= intOldHeight ) {
               intMaxSide = intOldWidth;
            } else {
               intMaxSide = intOldHeight;
            }

            if ( intMaxSide > maxSideSize ) {

               //set new width and height 
               double percent = maxSideSize / (double)intMaxSide;
               intNewWidth = Convert.ToInt32( percent * intOldWidth );
               intNewHeight = Convert.ToInt32( percent * intOldHeight );
            } else {
               intNewWidth = intOldWidth;
               intNewHeight = intOldHeight;
            }

            //create new bitmap 
            Bitmap bmpResized = new Bitmap( img, intNewWidth, intNewHeight );

            //save bitmap to disk 
            string path = Path.Combine( "C:\\Temp", test1.png" ) );

            bmpResized.Save( memory, fmtImageFormat );
            img.Save( path );

            //release used resources 
            img.Dispose();
            bmpResized.Dispose();
         } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.Write( e.Message );
         }
```

Can, the above code, be optimized for ASP.NET application ?

I think that if 1000 users are connected to my site, and maybe 20% of them upload an image with over 125px (as width and height) then the application may crash.

My friend recommended to use Canvas or Drawing2D library. What's happens if there already exists a file ? It is possible to overwrite ?

Sorry for stupid question. I need advices in this case.

Comment: 20% of users will upload an image at the same time?

Comment: We assume, yes. I showed a scenario, of course, the percentage could vary from case to another.

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where the ratio of upload/views is 1/4.

Comment: I strongly urge you to [use an server-safe library](http://imageresizing.net). There are [a lot of pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) to avoid. Right now you're (a) reducing the quality of the original by re-encoding it, (b) not protecting against memory leaks properly. Use `using` not `.Dispose`, (c) not encoding jpegs right, and (d) not detecting file formats or handling them appropriately. **It's worth using a 200KB library, trust me!** People writing their own server-side image processing stuff is the #1 reason asp.net servers die horrible deaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that 20% of users will upload an image in the same second. Of course you should make sure that you resize the image when it is uploaded and NOT when it is served. What is more if your server cannot do the work it will not crash but will put the users in the queue which will lead to slow response times.

Keep in mind that if you let anonymous users upload pictures you could be a subject of DOS attack and no amount of optimization can prevent that. You should add code that actively checks if the upload is legitimate and throttle new uploads when there are problems.

Finally if the code is really what you describe you do not need the memory stream at all you can read directly from the file when you create a bitmap and save directly to the file when you save a bitmap.

You can load the file with [this constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx) and save it with this [Save method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx)

Comment: No anonymous user will upload. I have filters and authentication system which allows some person to upload system. The above case is a scenario.

Comment: Do you have a performance problem now? If not then consider the first and second rules of optimization:
1. Don't do it. 2 (expert users only!) Don't do it yet!

Comment: One. The above code uses MemoryStream, if some people upload images, automatically call my function to resize them. Means, use memory. Is my code optimizable ?

Comment: It seems to me that you can save directly to the disk instead of saving to memory first
bmpResized.Save(path, fmtImageFormat); (updated in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this nuget package
http://nuget.org/packages/Simple.ImageResizer

How to use:
https://github.com/terjetyl/ImageResizer

I made use of the wpf classes which are supposed to be friendlier memorywise than the old System.Drawing classes.

Comment: Oh, if I want extra-package, of course I shouldn't post my question here. I need some code sample not extra-package. I don't need. Thx anyway for your effort

Comment: Then copy the code from the project in your application. This way you will have code sample and no extra package:)

Comment: WPF uses the same amount of memory that System.Drawing does, perhaps more - and while many of the garbage collection bugs were fixed, new ones were introduced. Also, WPF lacks GDI's 2-pass bicubic resizing, which is much better than WPF's Fant algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

On **Button click** while uploading file:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpPostedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(File1.PostedFile.InputStream);
     System.Drawing.Image objImage = ScaleImage(bmpPostedImage, 81);
     objImage.Save(SaveLocation,ImageFormat.Png);
     lblmsg.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
```

---

```
public static System.Drawing.Image ScaleImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxHeight)
        {
            var ratio = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;

            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            }
            return newImage;
        }
```

*More Detail* [Click here](http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-resize-image-while-uploading-in.html)

http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-resize-image-while-uploading-in.html